# Trying to convert '' in "" format

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to pass  this query "`select A||','||B AS "AB" from C`" as it is in a method so that it will execute.

but issue is as per my design 'AB' not coverted as "AB" in get method.

```
dt = conn.Get("select A||','||B AS 'AB' from C");
```

but in get method i want 'AB' as "AB" so that it will run in query

```
public DataTable Get(string cmdText, params string[] param)
    {}
```

how could i convert 'AB'as "AB".Any idea would be Appreciated.

Comment: `dt = conn.Get(@"select A||','||B AS ""AB"" from C");`

Comment: As far as Oracle is concerned, query would run OK without a *column alias* (i.e. `select a||','||b from c`), as well as if you don't quote the alias at all (i.e. `select a||','||b as ab from c`).

Comment: If the query is fixed and parameters are vary you can try to use Stored procedure in sql.